# WPF exception not getting handled

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i got a Usercontrol which has a Textbox with 'ValidatesOnExceptions' set to true

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding ElementName="_this"
             Path="VisibleValue"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
             Mode="TwoWay"
             ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

In the codebehind I have code wich will try to convert the input to an int, double...

```
private void SetValue(String visibleValue)
    {
        Object value = null;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(visibleValue)) {
            TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(Type);

            try {
                switch (typeCode) {
                    case TypeCode.Byte: {
                            Byte outValue = Byte.Parse(visibleValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            value = outValue;
                            break;
                        }
                    case TypeCode.Decimal: {
                            Decimal outValue = Decimal.Parse(visibleValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            value = outValue;
                            break;
                        }
                   }
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                if (value == null) {
                    HasValidValue = false;
                }
                else {
                    HasValidValue = true;
                }
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        Value = value;
        if (Value == null) {
            HasValidValue = false;
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Input text was null.");
        }
        else {
            HasValidValue = true;
        }
```

Don't get confused by the try...catch. Im throwing the catched exception again. The thing I dont understand is: When the Parse method throws an exception its getting handled, my programm keeps running and the textbox will get a red border.

But the 'ArgumentNullException' I throw further down is not getting handled. Can anybody explain this to me, and does anybody have a solution how i can get the same red border if value is null in this place as in the case when the Parse method throws an exception?

thanks in advance

EDIT: If i throw a FormatException instead of an ArgumentNullException everything works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Well you don't have a `catch` block for the `throw new ArgumentNullException`, so why are you expecting it to handle itself?

Comment: Set a `DataTrigger` that once the value is `null` you set a red border.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I really dont want to do that, there has to be a way using an exception

Comment: Is this something a normal control flow scenario? Meaning can the value at certain occasions be null?

Comment: What? I dont understand